# When I select text, onDidChangeTextEditorSelection does not trigger

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

```js
export function activate(context: ExtensionContext) {
      window.onDidChangeTextEditorSelection((evt: TextEditorSelectionChangeEvent) => {
            console.log(evt, 'event');
      })
}
```

When I was debugging, I did not see the console.log.
What should i do, thank you

Comment: in which console did you look, try `vscode.window.showInformationMessage`

Comment: vscode => help => toogle developer tool Open the built-in debug window。 vscode.window.showInformationMessage same no response

Comment: Sorry, it's ok again, I didn't do anything, maybe the editor is stuck.

Comment: I think you have to push it into `context.subscriptions`